# Set Highchart cursor/pointer with a click on a gmap polyline point

Tags: google-maps-api-3, highcharts

I'm using Highchart to show the distance and elevation of bicycle tracks, which I store and view as polylines on Gmap. In the chart the x-axis are the distance and the y-axis the elevation. The chart with clickable points looks like this demo chart (http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-ajax).

The first part: Going with the mouse over the chart and view the position on the track (gmap polyline point) is done.
Now I want to click on the track and view the point (elevation, distance) on the chart. To get the data (elevation, distance) is no problem, but:

How can I move the cursor/pointer (and ideally the small vertical line) in the chart to the corresponding point?

Comment: Not sure I follow. You want to click on a map in some other js object and have the highcharts char highlight its respective point?

Comment: Yes I think that correct. I have the gmap with a polyline and on the same page to the right the chart. The data for the chart (elevation and distance) I get from the polyline point by point and view it as line in the chart. Now I want to click on a point of the polyline (which gives me the pointnumber, the distance and elevation according to the chartline) and want that I can see (get marked / highlighted) that point on the chart-line.

Answer (score 0):

I have done an elevation chart using highcharts. In the presented method "r" is the response obtained from google elevation API and min and max the minimum and maximum height obtained from the elevation values. After the chart is presented to the user, if he clicks in the chart it will display a marker on the map on the corresponding point.

```
    var drawGraph = function (r, min,max) {
    var ec = $("#elevation-chart").empty();

    var counter=0;
    var arrayDistance_Elevation_Chart=[];//multidimensional array with accumulated distance corresponding to each elevation
    var arrayDistance_Position_Chart={};//object  with accumulated distance corresponding to each position

    var totalDistance=0;

        for (var i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {


           if(counter>0)
           {

           var latLngStart =r[i-1].location;
           var latLngEnd = r[i].location;
           //document.getElementById("distanceinfo").innerHTML=latLngStart;

           totalDistance+=getDistance(latLngStart,latLngEnd);

            totalDistance=round(totalDistance,3);
           arrayDistance_Elevation_Chart.push([totalDistance,round(r[i].elevation,3)]);
           arrayDistance_Position_Chart[totalDistance.toString()]=r[i].location;
           }
            counter++;
        }

         var chart = {
               zoomType: 'xy'
            };
            var subtitle = {
               text: ''   
            };
            var title = {
               text: 'Elevation'   
            };
            var xAxis = {

              title: {
                     text: 'Distance'
                 }
            };
            var yAxis = [
               { //  yAxis - Elevation
                    min: min,
                    max: max,      
                    title: {
                     text: 'Elevation',


                     style: {
                        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[8]
                     }
                  },
                  labels: {
                     format: '{value}',
                     style: {
                        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[8]
                     }
                  }
              }
            ];
            var tooltip = {
               shared: true
            };
            var legend = {
             align:'left',
             alignColumns:false,
             verticalAlign:true,

               floating: true,

               backgroundColor: (
                  Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor)
                  || '#FFFFFF'
            };
            var series = [
               {
                  name: 'Elevation',
                  yAxis: 0,
                  tickinterval: 1,
                    marker: {
                    enabled: true,
                    radius: 3
                 },
                   color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[8],
                  shadow: true,
                 tooltip: {
                     xDateFormat:  "%H:%M:%S"
                },  
                  data: arrayDistance_Elevation_Chart,

            }           

            ];   
           var  plotOptions={
            series: {
            point: {
                events: {
                mouseOver: function() {

                    hoverMarker.setVisible(true);
                    hoverMarker.setPosition(arrayDistance_Position_Chart[this.x.toString()]);
                },
                click: function() {


                    map.panTo(arrayDistance_Position_Chart[this.x.toString()]);
                }
               }

              }
             }};

            var json = {};   
            json.chart = chart;   
            json.title = title;
            json.subtitle = subtitle;      
            json.xAxis = xAxis;
            json.yAxis = yAxis;
            json.tooltip = tooltip;  
            json.legend = legend;  
            json.plotOptions=plotOptions;
            json.series = series;


            $('#elevationChart').highcharts(json);  

};
```